# Access Denied when creating AD Group with Workflow

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, active-directory

I'm trying to create AD Group via Workflow...I'm using a Workflow 2010 type on a Sharepoint Server 2013 .

When i try to launch the Workflow it cancels himself and says "Access Denied" ...
I tried to set AD authentication just before the add but there, it says taht the user or password is wrong.
But i'm sure they are good.
Any clue?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as I believe that this cannot qualify as one but I believe that this function is not supported natively in SharePoint but you can look into Nintex Workflows as they claim that you can provision AD users with their solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an AD group from a SharePoint workflow...

Comment: Do you have a source for this statement? It is always nice to have a source in your answers to give them mor credibility :)